# Ошибка при установке October CMS

Tags: cms, openserver, october

Устанавливаю October CMS на локальный "Open Server"
При завершении установки выдает ошибку:

```
    call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
    class 'System\Models\Parameters' not found
```

До этого ставил бета версию "октября" проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это баг установщика. Открой редактором файл

```
./install_files/php/Installer.php
```

И в методах `setProjectDetails()` и `setCoreBuild()` (525 - 547 строки) строка:

```
call_user_func('System\Models\Parameters::set', ...
```

должна быть

```
call_user_func('System\Models\Parameter::set', ...
```